# Undefined index on my checkbooking.php

Tags: php, html

This is the error I have: 
[image: This is the error i have]

Below is my php booking page . I have trouble solving the error. I faced in check booking page below. I can't find the undefined index error for service, eventdate, Customer ID. Can you help me?

```
   <?php

   session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))
   {
    header("Location:login.php");
   }
    $un = $_SESSION["MM_Username"];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "m3_162931g_db");

    $sql = "SELECT * from customer where Username='$un'";

    $user = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $oneUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user);

    ?> 



     <content>
     <h1>Booking Page</h1>

   <form action="checkbook.php" method="post" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
 <div class="container">
<label><b>Services :</b></label>

<select name ="service" placeholder="Select Service">
                <option value="1" >Wedding</option>    
                <option value="2" >Same Day Printing</option>     
                <option value="3" >Instagram Images</option>     
                <option value="4" >Family Photo</option>
                <option value="5" >Green Screen Photography</option> 
                <option value="6" >Corporate Event</option> 
                <option value="7" >Business Portrait</option> 
                <option value="8" >Advertisment Printing</option> 
                <option value="9" >Award Ceremonies</option> 

            </select>

  <br>
<label><b>Date :</b></label>
<input type="date" name="eventdate" required>
  <input type="text" id="hide" name="CustomerID" value="<?php echo 
 $oneUser['CustomerID']; ?>"  hidden="hidden" >




<div class="clearfix">
  <button type="reset" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
  <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Book</button>
</div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

this is my checkbook php page .Its shows undefined index error for service ,eventdate, customerID

```
     <?php
     session_start();
      $service = $_POST['service'];
      $eventdate = $_POST['eventdate'];
      $customerID = $_POST['CustomerID'];
      $bs = "B";
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "m3_162931G_db");

      $sql = "insert into booking(ProductID,CustomerID,Booking_Date,status) 
      values ('$service','$customerID','$eventdate', '$bs')";

      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if ($result){
       header("Location:orderhistory.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to check your variables and that its POST request.. plus fill the SQLi hole. If you did a POST request it would work as it would then redirect to `orderhistory.php` which would not give you enough time to take a screenshot.

Comment: Have you verified that your query is returning rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you need to check your variable like that

```
if (isset($_POST['service'])) {
      $service = $_POST['service'];
      $eventdate = $_POST['eventdate'];
      $customerID = $_POST['CustomerID'];
      $bs = "B";
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "m3_162931G_db");

      $sql = "insert into booking(ProductID,CustomerID,Booking_Date,status) 
      values ('$service','$customerID','$eventdate', '$bs')";

      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if ($result){
       header("Location:orderhistory.php");
    }

}
```

Comment: i try and they will go to the orderhistory